# How to dynamically populate iron-list elements

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, web-component

So I have an iron-list element for a user's data history. **The iron-list is not part of a custom element. It is simply on the page.** I want to populate once the user has successfully logged in. Perhaps it is just my inexperience with polymer, but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this. First attempt (simplified for reading, e.g. I don't actually use jquery, there's lots of error-handling code I'm omitting, etc):

```
<iron-list as="item" style='height: 100%;' id='history-list'>
  <template>
    <div style='min-height: 140px;'>
      <ul>
        <!-- various fields for each record as list items -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
<script>
  //once user is logged in
  var items = $.getJSON('userhistoryscript');
  //setAttribute doesn't work either
  document.getElementById('history-list').items = items;
</script>
```

I would swear this worked in an earlier version of Polymer. But it doesn't seem to work now, which is fine, but I need an alternative.

Some alternatives I've considered:

1. Have iron-ajax element in same DOM scope and set '
   the URL once the user is logged in to trigger the
   xhr request. I'm not sure whether or not that'd work.
2. Wrap the list in a custom element and use an
   iron-meta-query per chrisW's answer.

Those options are *terrible*. I cannot believe there is no simpler way to accomplish this feat. How do I *conditionally* fetch data based on user input and *dynamically* add an iron-list to the page (or update one that's already there)? Is there really no API for this use case?

## UPDATE

Thank you for your answers. Turns out that my original code actually works fine: it was actually a build process issue. For some reason iron-list did not get installed when I installed the project dependencies through bower. I took out the vulcanized import (which must not have contained a ref to iron-list either) and imported all the elements directly, then I got the 404 and figured out what had happened.

Answer (score 2):

I think that for best practices, you should use `this.$.historyList` to refeer id on this element. Anyway, when you get data to populate `iron-list`you should use `this.set('items', data);` An example using your element looks like:

```
<iron-list>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="history">
        <!--history.property-->
    </template>
 </iron-list>

<script>
  Polymer({
    properties:{
        data:{type:Array, value:[],}
    },
    _functionToSetDataWhenUserIsLoggedIn: function(data){
        this.set('data',data);
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### Edit

An example of iron-list

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <iron-ajax url="data.json" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>
  <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
    <template>
      <div>
        Name: <span>[[item.name]]</span>
      </div>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
</template>
```

This example is using an ajax call that executes automatically and populates the `iron-list`without the need to create a customized element.

More about `iron-list` on:
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't necessarily planning on wrapping the iron-list in a custom element. Your answer seems to be suggesting that the only way to accomplish my end is to do so? That script tag I have above is just a script in a separate js file. Is the only way to dynamically set the content to have the script that fetches it in the same local DOM?

Comment: Why are you dom repeating the iron list. Shouldn't that be outside the template? And then have the <ul> inside the template

Comment: I had understood the question differently @ChrisW, I have edited my answer.

Comment: That edit is straight from the element catalog page and not at all my use case. I want to *dynamically* fetch that json data once and *only once* the user is logged in (otherwise how do I know which user's history to fetch?). My question is how? Yeah sure I can wrap the whole thing in a custom element and expose an API to do so but can't this be done more simply? That 'solution' I posited seems to couple things that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't entirely understand your question. Hope this helps.

```
  <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
    <template>
      <div>
        Name: <span>[[item.name]]</span>
      </div>
    </template>
  </iron-list>   

    properties:{
        data:{type:Array, value:[],}
    },
    // the attached function is automatically called 
    attached: function() {
       // Use an iron meta in the element that you keep track in of login information
       // or create an onLogin listener
       var isLoggedIn = new Polymer.IronMetaQuery({key: 'isLoggedIn'}).value, 
       if (isLoggedIn) {
          var jsonData = $.getJSON('userhistoryscript'); 
          this.set('data',jsonData);
       }
    }
```

Side note, when access elements by ids in Polymer elements, make sure you do it this way:

```
this.$.elementId
```

or

```
Polymer.dom('#elementId')
```

### Edit since you don't want to create a custom polymer element

[Source Code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/blob/master/demo/index.html)

```
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <iron-list id="list">

    </iron-list>  

  </template>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('onLogin', function(event) {
      var list = document.getElementById('#list');
      var jsonDataObjects = $.getJSON('userhistoryscript'); 
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonDataObjects.length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.textContent = jsonDataObjects[i].info; // change this line
        list.appendChild(div);
      }

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: `iron-meta-query` seems to be just what I needed. I'll test it out.

Comment: @JaredSmith hope this helps. The iron ajax elemen in the other answer is the more polymeresque way to get json

Comment: Figured it out. Updated question. Thanks for helping, +1